# how can I change this solr query

Tags: solr

Here is my query to solr when user type some character fr example I

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/db/select?q=(name:I*) OR (lastname: I*) OR (midname:I*)&fl=name, midname,lastname&rows=5&wt=json&indent=true&group=true&group.field=lastname&group.ngroups=true";
```

How should I change  the query to solr so Icanget

1. first - those people with name and lastname that start with this characrer
2. if none - second - those people that only first name starts with ths character
3. if none -third - those people with only lastname that starts with this character
4. and if there is none - those where middlename start with I

Answer (score 1):

There can be no check for 0 results unless you are writing a custom search component or firing query again based on previous queries result.

For the Ordering you can boost the query parts so the conditions can be match

something like e.g. `(name:I*)^10 OR (lastname: I*)^5 OR (midname:I*)^1`